# Not able to create Web DB on Separate Web SQL server

Tags: installation, sql-database, scaling

We are installing Sitecore 9.3 using XP scaled topology, and while setting up the CM server we have to install only the Web Database to the Web SQL server and other Databases (Master, Core, Experience Forms... ) to the Master SQL server. The ConnectionString on the CM server for the web node should also point to the Web SQL server, and the other databases should point to the Master SQL server. But with the current scripts/JSON configurations which we got from the Sitecore package, there is no way to distinguish the SQL servers.
Everything is getting installed on the Same SQL server.

Any thoughts!!

Comment: If you want to use Sitecore scripts, maybe just install web db together with other databases and then move it to the proper sql server?

Comment: I can do that, but how the connectionStrings will be changed for the web node in the CM server, I have to point it to the CD SQL server without any manual changes in the config.

Comment: Why can't you change it manually in the config?

Comment: Because i am creating a deployment mechanism using TFS and it should be automated for all the environments ( QA, Staging, Production etc.)

Comment: If you are using Azure web app, move your connection strings to web app configuration. Or use tokens in your pipeline to update the connection strings at release.

Comment: Are you using XP1-SingleDeveloper or XP1-Distributed?